# aspx file content replaced by whitespace characters, Is there anyway to recover aspx files?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, recovery, recover, file-recovery

I was working on some aspx page, and suddenly my system was crashed, when I rebooted my system, file was there, but when I opened that file from solution explorer, file content was replaced by some whitespace characters,and opened in notepad file. I have checked its size and it was around 31 kb.

Is there any way to recover its content ? its around 4-5 days of my work

Comment: Right click on the file, Properties -> tab "Previous Versions". If you have previous versions feature enabled for that drive, you can recover your file's version from yesterday.

Comment: Nope, It says "There are no previous version available" :(

Comment: Bad luck. That's why, after I reinstall Windows, I always check that file history is enabled for all drives. Saved me several times.

Comment: That's great, can you please tell me how can enable this file history, so I can save my self for next time ?

Comment: [this should help](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-hardware/how-to-enable-volume-shadow-copy-in-windows-7/faaf7490-d929-47a6-a12f-1bf100db66e5)

Comment: @DotNetIsMyPower See this article: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/Previous-versions-of-files-frequently-asked-questions section "How are previous versions created?".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced the same problem with a file today and overcame it successfully. :D

Felt freaking heavenly after getting my file back ... :D \m/ :D

Here is the solution. Actually, there can be two types of solution of recovering corrupted files I found.

> **Scenario:** Your file is corrupted (ie. null or space everywhere in the file while the size is ok)
>
> **Solution #1:** Using file recovery software.
>
> File recovery softwares can recover a file when it is already deleted.
>   In our scenario, your file is not deleted but corrupted. So how to use
>   the software in this case!!!!
>
> - Just delete your file
> - Try to recover your deleted files with popular file recovery softwares
>
> And voila ... it is recovered ... :D
>
> The recovery software I used is [Recuva](http://www.piriform.com/recuva). Worked perfectly.
>
> **Solution #2:** If its a web content, like CSS/Javascript/html etc.
>
> You can collect the last working copy of the file from browser cache,
>   IF and ONLY IF you hadn't opened the corrupted webpage in that brower.

The thought that help me finding the first solution is from

**Mark Twain** - "Never argue with stupid people, they will drag you down to their level and then beat you with experience."

While I was thinking how to use this recovery software, I thought about this quote and said myself "LETS DRAG THE FILE DOWN TO THE LEVEL, WHERE RECOVERY SOFTWARE CAN RECOVER" ... :D

Comment: million thanks! recuva worked for me saved me a ton of lost time

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you do not have backups or svn/git repositories or the last resource like the shadow copies.

I guess your best bet is by using some file recovery tools like [OnTrack](http://www.krollontrack.com/data-recovery/recovery-software/) or [Recuva](http://www.piriform.com/recuva)

Comment: Ya, Actually we do use TFS in our organization but, I didn't checked in my code since 4-5 days, So I don't have any backups, anyways let me try this software

anyways, Thanks buddy

Comment: you should shelve your code in TFS if you don't want to check in

Comment: hey, this both software are for file recover, but actually I haven't lost my file, its there, but I lost its content. Is there any way to recover its content?

Comment: I used OnTrack a couple of times and, if I'm not mistaken, it should have a functionality to do sector by sector recovery or something similar. If that should not work I can not think of others solutions.